# How to define an selector if the elements are dynamic element

Tags: css, testing, dynamic, functional-testing, testcafe

snippet code on img below

I want to assert text on `p clas = jss94 jss102 jss127 jss264 jss265`
This class is dynamic, and all the class before it also dynamic. So how to get the text or how to select the element if there's no static id/class/text on it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [`withAttribute`](https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/test-api/selecting-page-elements/selectors/functional-style-selectors.html#withattribute) method:

```js
.withAttribute('class', /jss\w+\sjss\w+/)
```

Please refer to the following:

1. https://github.com/DevExpress/testcafe/issues/4872#issuecomment-599919313
2. https://regex101.com/r/VR5mJ0/1
3. https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/test-api/selecting-page-elements/examples-of-working-with-dom-elements.html#select-elements-with-dynamic-ids

Comment: You are welcome. Could you please ["accept" this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)?

Answer (score 2):

See the ways to select elements with dynamic identificators [here](https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/test-api/selecting-page-elements/examples-of-working-with-dom-elements.html#select-elements-with-dynamic-ids).

Comment: I tried all but no one worked on my side. I tried    .expect(Selector('h6').withAttribute('class', '/jss/i /jss/i').withText('Chat with\w+/')); but getting error   1) An assertion method is not specified.

Comment: @HerawatiManurung it looks like you're using a string and not a regex like you want. Try adjusting `/jss/i` so it does not have quotation marks around it. You may also need to make further adjustments as well.

Comment: Sorry I dont understand, I tried ''''.expect(Selector('h6').withAttribute('class', 'jss jss').withText('Chat with\w+/'))'''' but still the same

Comment: @HerawatiManurung Please specify what you expect from this selector. For example, if you just want to check whether or not this selector exists on the page, you can use the following: `.expect(Selector('h6').withAttribute('class', 'jss jss').withText('Chat with\w+/').exists).ok()`. (refer to [https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/test-api/selecting-page-elements/selectors/using-selectors.html#check-if-an-element-exists](https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/test-api/selecting-page-elements/selectors/using-selectors.html#check-if-an-element-exists))

Comment: I used ````.expect(Selector('h6').withAttribute('class', 'jss jss').withText('Chat with\w+/').exists).ok()```` but got another error "expected false to be truthy"

Comment: @HerawatiManurung, please provide your test page example so that we can find a suitable solution for you.

Comment: Here's the code ````<header class ="jss24 jss30 jss81 jss85">
<div class = "jss90 jss92 jss91" >
 <h5 class = "jss94 jss110" style = "flex-grow: 1;" >
     "Chat with "
     "Herawati"
     "Manurung"
 </h5>
</div>
</header>```` I want to expect element withText Chat with .... is exists, where ..... can replace with other user